# How to remove the last three elements in a list using Dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

if you have list like this ...

```
      List<String> data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5',..... n];
```

how can you remove the last three element knowing that you don't know the length of the list, i tried to use removeRange() but it didn't go well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code

```
void main() {
  List data  = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
  data .length = data.length - 3;//put your how many list item you want to remove eg.1,2,3,...n
  print(data);
}
```

Result-> `[1, 2]`

Comment: Nice way to truncate  a list ;)

Comment: Legend!, thank you this solution is better than remove range

Comment: When the user supplies data with less than 3 elements, this will throw an error

Comment: @qrsngky just one thing if you provide number of list item less that 3 then also decrease/minimize the how many list item you want to delete eg. if you put 3 or 2 items in list then change the number of deleted item digit like 1,2 etc

Comment: how to remove from the first

Comment: @KKMuhammedFazil what do you want I cant understand

Comment: i need last 7 numbers in the list.

Comment: @KKMuhammedFazil you have `List data  = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];` this type of list and which elements do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeRange` like this:

```
data.removeRange(data.length - 3, data.length);
```

Comment: RangeError (start): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: -3

Answer (score 0):

And one more way:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var myList = List.generate(10, (n) => n);
  print(myList);
  myList.length -= 3;
  print(myList);
}
```

which results in:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Yeah, I was pleased to see that it works!